# Rails self referential relationship for quasi versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I’m looking for the most elegant way to handle a self referential relationship in my rails model. I have an “answer” which could be used as a basis for another “answer.” There aren’t necessarily versions of each other since a significant amount of information could change from “answer” to the other. I’m looking to maintain a sort of multi level parent child relationship so I can trace back the authors, content, etc..   I’ve looked at a couple of gems, but I’m hesitant to introduce something like that, as it may be overkill.  Is there a preferred “rails way” of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd use ancestry if you have a tree-like structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to create a tree structure where each answer has a reference to its "parent" answer. This is a common use-case, and there's a [whole slew of gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting) that help solve this problem.

At it's most basic, you'll need some sort of `parent_id` column on your answers that references the parent. At that point it's really easy to create methods and scopes that grab the parent, children, siblings, etc.

Since your use-case seems pretty simple, writing your own code to manage the tree is probably fine. However, there is something to be said for using existing code that's been well tested and had the kinks worked out. If nothing else, it can save you time in writing your own unit tests. [ActsAsTree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) is about as basic as they come. It shipped with earlier versions of Rails, so if you find your needs growing for some reason, just about every other gem in this space has an upgrade path you can follow.